# Get url value using req.param

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I have a url like this

`/goto/data/12345`

I need to read 12345 using req.param in sails js .

Defined routes like this

`/goto/data/:id`

Comment: Share the git repo or code?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
req.params.id
```

In [Sails.js](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-params) this is the basic syntax.

Comment: got undefined value.

Comment: Print the whole req in a console.log maybe can help to understand the structure of the request. Like:
console.log(req);

Comment: can u give me a proper sol.?? i have done all this things

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
req.param('id')
```

Reference: [req-param-doc](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-param)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple possibilities:

- Use `req.allParams()`

  ```
  let {id} = req.allParams()
  ```
- Use `req.body` if your request is not a `GET`
- Use `req.param`

  ```
  let id = req.param('id')
  ```

  or

  ```
  let id = req.param.id
  ```

Make sure your route is configured correctly and the kind of your HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

It should be.

```
req.params.id
```

But, if you got undefined, please check you `routes.js` it may be got override by another routes. Ex:

```
'get /goto/data/find': 'GotoController.find'
'get /goto/data/:id': 'GotoController.getById'
```